# CMake VS2008 CE cross compile - change (deployment - remote directory)

Tags: deployment, cmake, cross-compiling

Is it possible to change the visual studio (2008) deployment - remote directory setting from within a CMakeLists.txt. The default CMake is using: "%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES%\"

The goal I like to achieve is having multiple projects deploy to the same remote directory. All dll and exe files nicely together on the remote machine for debugging purposes.

PS.
Is there a general approach to change VisualStudio settings, I reckon there are other settings needed to be customized.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?